# Running android project

Tags: android, eclipse

I made an app and after many days I want to run it again . Because of my project was on SVN for using the app I follow this steps :
1.File--> New--> Other--> SVN--> Project From SVN ... and so no

But when I right click on the project name to run it there isn't item call "1 android application"

[image]

when I want to config it for running ,in Android tab --> Project--> Browser I can't see my project and it's list is empty .

[image]

Also I can't find AVD for running on it (I made three AVD already...)

[image]

How can I fix it... :(

please guide me.
Thanks ;)

Comment: Normally, when you click CTRL+F11, Eclipse will ask you how you want to run the application.  You should select Android App and it should configure the project for you. In case you do not have any emulator, It will ask you to create one.

Comment: When I press CTRL+F11 , ith shows me "The selection cannot be launched, and there are no recent launches."

Comment: Try cleaning the project, and if not, as an answer suggest, import the project again.

Comment: I clean the project already and also I import it for many time,But there is the problem again... :(

Comment: Maybe the problem is in your Android SDK, Did you upgrade it recently or something?

Comment: I update it about 2 or 3 mobth ago. But I can run my other app.Juas I can't run this project.I don't know ,how fix it ...

Comment: What do you have in the Android tab of your project properties?

Comment: I haven't Android tab in properties of the project.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your AVDs are running Android version with target API. For example if your project is for API 14+, no AVD with API < 14 will be listen on Target AVD list.

Comment: I use <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" /> and I made an AVD with API 8 .but there is the problem again...

Answer (score 0):

In the comments you told you are not seeing any Android tab in the project properties, you should be seeing something like this:

[image: Android Tab]

I would think then, that you do not have the Android SDK well configured, or your project is not set to be an Android Project.

Try re installing the Android SDK. Or creating a new Android project and copy all the files in that new project.

Comment: Honey,I know that , but there isn't any item call "android" on left the properties window.

Comment: Then I do not know, if you create right now an Android project, the Android tab is there?

Comment: Thanks for your answers... my problem solved. I have to import the problem like this :.File-->New-->Other-->SVN-->Project From SVN-->press Next-->tick using existing repository location-->press Next-->press finish-->in new windows tick "Find projects in the children of the selected resource"-->press finish

Comment: Um, to import a git project you simply import it as a normal project. I dont't know why it is not the same for svn.